# How to use python to take log of a whole matrix by sign

Tags: python, numpy

there are many positive numbers and negative numbers in a matrix, I want to take  log for all numbers by sign, which means: for positive numbers, just take log directly, for negative numbers, maybe we can change them to positive, take log, and then change back to negative?
when I use np.log10, the negative numbers will be Nah.

Comment: First take the absolute value of the matrix; apply `log10` to the result.

Comment: I mean take the logs of the absolute value of my matrix, sorry for my ambiguous expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take the logs of the absolute value of your array, then where the original array is negative, inverse the sign of the log value. If that's indeed what you wish to do, this would achieve what you want:

given the array:

```
arr = np.random.randn(10)

array([ 0.01709907, -1.5970228 ,  0.60764499,  0.10409295,  0.04213179,
   -0.51913205, -1.38669546,  0.0965971 ,  0.65106376, -2.48521279])
```

You can apply the transformation I described using:

```
logs = np.log10(np.abs(arr))
logs[arr < 0] = logs[arr < 0]*-1
```

resulting in this:

```
>>> logs
array([-1.76702751, -0.20331112, -0.21635008, -0.98257868, -1.37539009,
    0.28472216, -0.14198109, -1.01503591, -0.18637648, -0.39536358])
```